# How to measure the approx completion time of a process at its start time?

Tags: linux, windows, cpu, process, r

I am running an R process using R shiny as the front end. My process takes a long time approx 1 hour to complete. But in order to show the progress notification bar, I need approx time to show.

I am also using parallel process in between.

Is there any way in this world to get the time a process will take to complete at its initialization?

Answer (score 1):

If the process takes an hour to complete, start showing the progress bar after 1 minute and show "calculating estimated time to completion"  during the first minute with a countdown in seconds.

Use an algorithm that allows you to update the progress bar not solely based on time but on actual work done so that if your parallel process takes a lot of the CPU away, the progress bar will go slower as well.